# erlang gen_tcp connecting to erlang.org claims a 404

Tags: erlang, httpclient, erlang-ports

context: JA's "Programming Erlang" 2ed, chapter 16 on files, page 256, example on working with parsing urls from a Binary.

The steps suggested (after writing code for the scavenge_urls module) are these:

```
B = socket_examples:nano_get_url("www.erlang.org"),
L = scavenge_urls:bin2urls(B),
scavenge_urls:urls2htmlFile(L,"gathered.html").
```

And that fails (subtly) - the list L ends up being empty. Running the first step on its own, a strange thing is observed - it does return a binary, but it's not the binary I was looking for:

```
9> B.
<<"HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nServer: nginx\r\nDate: Sun, 19 Nov 2017 01:57:07 GMT\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"...>>
 shows that this is where the problem lies.
```

yet in the browser all's good with the mothership! I was able to complete the exercise by replacing the call to socket_examples:nano_get_urls/1 with, first, CURLing for the same url, dumping that into a file, and then file:read_file/1. The next steps all ran fine.

Peeking inside the socket_examples module, I see this:

```
nano_get_url(Host) ->
    {ok,Socket} = gen_tcp:connect(Host,80,[binary, {packet, 0}]), %% (1)
    ok = gen_tcp:send(Socket, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"),  %% (2)
    receive_data(Socket, []).

receive_data(Socket, SoFar) ->
    receive
        {tcp,Socket,Bin} ->    %% (3)
            receive_data(Socket, [Bin|SoFar]);
        {tcp_closed,Socket} -> %% (4)
            list_to_binary(reverse(SoFar)) %% (5)
    end.
```

Nothing looks suspicious. First it establishes the connection, next it fires a GET, and then it receives the response. I've never before had to explicitly connect first, and fire a GET second, my http client libraries hid that from me. So maybe I don't know what to look for... and I sure trust Joe's code doesn't have any glaring mistakes! =) Yet the lines with comments (3),(4) and (5) aren't something I fully understand.

So, any ideas, fellow Erlangers?
Thank a bunch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not Erlang. It looks like the server running erlang.org requires a `Host` header as well:

```
$ nc www.erlang.org 80
GET / HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 19 Nov 2017 05:51:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 162
Connection: close
Vary: Accept-Encoding

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
$ nc www.erlang.org 80
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.erlang.org

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 19 Nov 2017 05:51:50 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 12728
Connection: close
Vary: Accept-Encoding

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

Your Erlang code also works with the Host header after `GET HTTP/1.0\r\n`:

```
1> Host = "www.erlang.org".
"www.erlang.org"
2> {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:connect(Host, 80, [binary, {packet, 0}]).
{ok,#Port<0.469>}
3> ok = gen_tcp:send(Socket, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.erlang.org\r\n\r\n").
ok
4> flush().
Shell got {tcp,#Port<0.469>,
               <<"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: nginx\r\n...>>
Shell got {tcp_closed,#Port<0.469>}
```

Comment: I expected this had nothing to do with Erlang code, but wasn't sure what it was about, nor why it would be that way, missing from the book's errata too.

Comment: here's a follow-up question then, @Dogbert - how did you figure out the server needs that particular header? Because nothing in 404 seems to indicate some header missing is the problem with a request.. is that some fine details of a HTTP standard I am missing? It just seems to be so very strange..

Comment: My clue was that the 404 response included `HTTP/1.1` even though our request was `HTTP/1.0`. `HTTP/1.1` requests must have a Host header: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23. When I tried the request with a Host header, it worked. :)

Comment: Huh, very interesting. And this too:
All Internet-based HTTP/1.1 servers MUST respond with a 400 (Bad Request) status code to any HTTP/1.1 request message which lacks a Host header field.

Comment: It actually does do that if you do `GET / HTTP/1.1`. It probably should do that for `HTTP/1.0` requests as well.

Comment: Aha! That's exactly how it worked. Thank a bunch mate!